# How to pass AJAX response to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to pass my AJAX response on success, basically after the content has been loaded, to a javascript variable which I can eventually utilise perhaps in other functions. I have this code which works:

```
var json; // Variable with Global Scope

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/...",
    dataType: "JSON",
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {

        json = JSON.parse(response.value1); // value1 as in {"value1":1234} from the url.

        console.log("Json Parse Data 1: " + json);

    }
});

console.log("Json Parse Data 2: " + json);
```

According to my research, the use of `async: false` is deprecated given that it freezes the browser load until the AJAX Request is complete. So, an alternative to this would be the following:

```
function getValue(callback){ 

    var json;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/...",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {

            var json = JSON.parse(response.value1);

            console.log("Json Parse Data 1: " + json);

            callback(json);

        }
    });
}

function on_Complete(json) { // When request is complete, do this

    console.log("Json Parse Data 2: " + json);

}

getValue(on_Complete); // Here I call the second function to do console.log("Json Parse Data 2: " + json)
```

This comes very close, but what I am trying to achieve with the second code is passing the `var json;` as a callback and return its value to the second function after the request is successful instead of `console.log("Json Parse Data 2: " + json)`. Some along lines this:

```
function on_Complete(json) {

    var result = json;

    return result; // Or directly return json;

}

var value1 = getValue(on_Complete); // Making this variable equal to json returned in on_Complete(json)

console.log("Json Parse Data 2: " + value1);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Quentin The other question passes the callback to a function, I want to pass it to a variable.

Comment: As the answers to the duplicate question point out: That is impossible.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Have a nice day! @Quentin